# How to store JWT token properly using Laravel 5.4 and Vue.js 2

Tags: javascript, laravel, rest, api, vue.js

I'm writing an API using Laravel 5.4 and connect to it from frontend written in Vue.js 2. After login API gets back a token to me, so how and where should I store the token in a frontend? Now, I'm using localStorage for that but it doesn't seem to be a right way.

**This is how I check for token:**

```
router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {
  if(to.meta.requiresAuth) { 
    if(store.getters.logged || window.localStorage.getItem('access_token')) { 
      next();
    }
    else {
      next('/login');
    }
  }
  else {
    next();
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

`localStorage` is not async so after login, you would need to refresh the entire page which is very bad UX to refresh single page app which I believe is what you develop since you use Vue.

What I can suggest instead is `localForage` which is nothing more than async `localStorage`. It is promise based and the syntax looks very similar to `localStorage`.

**Example:**

```
localforage.setItem(key, value, successCallback)
localforage.getItem('access_token', myCallback);
```

And to send the token in every request to backend you should use `vue.http.interceptors`.

**Example:**

```
Vue.http.interceptors.push((request, next)  => {
  request.headers['Authorization'] = auth.getAuthHeader()
    next((response) => {
      if(response.status == 401 ) {
        auth.logout();
        router.go('/login?unauthorized=1');
      }
   });
});
```

Read more on this in the [Docs](https://github.com/localForage/localForage).

Comment: My code isn't working properly only in one situation: It doesn't expire. If I close my browser and then open it up I can access my `/admin` route without any problem. So, in my localStorage I always have the token.